# Send devExpress Session as parameter in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, devexpress, xpo

I have an exception when I want to send a devExpress session in a composite type in WCF.
I tried to make it serializable but I still get the error

> information: Type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` with data
>   contract name
>   `SqlConnection:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.SqlClient`
>   is not expected. Consider using a `DataContractResolver` if you are
>   using `DataContractSerializer` or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

This the DataContract That I used.

```
[DataContract] 
[Serializable] 
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Session))] 
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SqlConnection))] 
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SqlParameter))] 
public class CompositeType 
{
 Session sValue ; 
 [DataMember] 
 public Session SessionValue 
 { get {return sValue; } set {sValue = value; } } 

  }
```

I use also a method that send this class as parameter

```
void GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about data or class that you send?

Comment: `[DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Session))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(SqlConnection))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(SqlParameter))]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        Session sValue ;

        [DataMember]
        public Session SessionValue
        {
            get {return sValue; }
            set {sValue = value; }
        }
    }`
This the DataContract That I used.
I use also a method that send this class as parameter 
`        void GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
`

Comment: Add to your question as well please. And are you storing something with a database connection in session?

Comment: My Goal is to create a session from devexpress xpo interface and then send it to wcf service to fill it with the information from the database

Comment: XPO already has a built-in mechanism for transferring data via WCF services. Can you explain why this is not suitable for you? See: [Transferring Data via WCF Services](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/10018/feature-center/connecting-to-a-data-store/transferring-data-via-wcf-services)

Answer (score 2):

XPO objects are tied to the data store via Session and you cannot send them over the wire.

If you want just to transfer raw data between computers, use a [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). XPO will retrieve data from the database on one side, and you will retrieve the data on the other side using WCF client methods.

XPO also supports a more complex scenario. If you want to use XPO on the client side but cannot create a direct database connection for security reasons, you can implement the [IDataStore](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.Xpo.DB.IDataStore) interface as a contract on the WCF side.

It is easy to implement the IDataStore interface, because all you need is to wrap an existing [Data Store Adapter](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2114/fundamentals/database-systems-supported-by-xpo). All Data Store Adapters implement the IDataStore interface. XPO's [Data Access Layer](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2121/feature-center/connecting-to-a-data-store/data-access-layer) can use any IDataStore as a data source. This blog explains this approach: [XPO is good for distributed applications](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xpo/archive/2006/04/13/xpo-is-good-for-distributed-applications.aspx).

Moreover, XPO has built-in WCF service and client components that already implement the IDataStore interface. All you need is to put them together. See examples here: [Transferring Data via WCF Services](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/10018/feature-center/connecting-to-a-data-store/transferring-data-via-wcf-services).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. it's very helpful to understand the devexpress data transfer.
I found some example that should be helpful [https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xpo/archive/2011/05/17/xpo-11-1-sneak-peek-wcf-services-for-iobjectlayer.aspx] 
But my goal is that I should have a request-reply WCF. I think  it isn't possible with devexpress and wcf with dataLayer transfer. 
I will implement another solution . thanks

Comment: Uranus please can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647272/threadsafedatalayer-and-idatalayer-devexpress-xpo-cant-map-classinfo-to-same-ta